# Error: element types must all match for conversion to list terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform module with below variable.tf. I am creating a module for launch template which will have options for instance type and instance attributes.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "ec2_launch_template" {
  type = list(object({
    name                     = string
    image_id                 = string
    instance_type            = optional(string)
    key_name                 = string
    lt_security_group_names = list(string)
    user_data = string
    default_version = number
    iam_instance_profile_arn = string
    core_count = optional(number)
    threads_per_core = optional(number)
    instance_requirements = optional(list(object({
            cpu_max = optional(number)
            cpu_min = optional(number)
            memory_max = optional(number)
            memory_min = optional(number)
    })))
    ebs_volume = optional(list(object({
      device_name = optional(string)

            volume_type = optional(string)
            volume_size = optional(number)
            snapshot_id  = optional(string)
            kms_key_arn = optional(string)
            encrypted = optional(bool)
            ebs_block_delete_on_termination = optional(bool)
            iops     = optional(number)
            throughput  = optional(number)
    })))

    tags                     = map(string)
  }))
  description = "EC2 launch template to create, with their properties"
  default     = []
}
```

The .tfvars I am using is below

**.tfvars**

```
ec2_launch_template = [
  {
    "core_count": "3",
    "default_version": "1",
    "ebs_volume": [],
    "iam_instance_profile_arn": "arn:aws:iam::114833826347:instance-profile/testing-ec2-role-manoj",
    "image_id": "ami-05637405f4b0773e4",
    "instance_requirements": [],
    "instance_type": "t2.medium",
    "key_name": "RDSTEST",
    "lt_security_group_names": [
      "RDP"
    ],
    "name": "testtemplate6",
    "tags": {
      "Name": "testtemplate6"
    },
    "threads_per_core": "2",
    "user_data": "testdata.sh"
  },
  {
    "core_count": "4",
    "default_version": "1",
    "ebs_volume": [
      {
        "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
        "ebs_block_delete_on_termination": false,
        "encrypted": true,
        "iops": "10000",
        "kms_key_arn": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:114833826347:key/7ed65523-f8ec-40f1-889e-ee65f7e58172",
        "snasphot_id": "snap-00a70b80c54bb6af5",
        "throughput": "125",
        "volume_size": "50",
        "volume_type": "gp3"
      }
    ],
    "iam_instance_profile_arn": "arn:aws:iam::114833826347:instance-profile/testing-ec2-role-manoj",
    "image_id": "ami-05637405f4b0773e4",
    "instance_requirements": [
      {
        "cpu_max": "3",
        "cpu_min": "2",
        "memory_max": "80",
        "memory_min": "20"
      }
    ],
    "instance_type": null,
    "key_name": "RDSTEST",
    "lt_security_group_names": [
      "RDP"
    ],
    "name": "testtemplate5",
    "tags": {
      "Name": "testtemplate5"
    },
    "threads_per_core": "2",
    "user_data": "testdata.sh"
  }
]
```

We are getting below error:

**element types must all match for conversion to list.**

In order to debug, we tried with variable type as any. It's still giving the same issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The code along with the exact line where the error is happening should be added to the question.

Comment: It's giving error in line 1 of variables.tf. So I can't figure out why exactly the issue is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were defining variables which were not needed. Once we commented those it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Variables of type **number**:

In your definition, all the variables that have been declared as `optional(number)`, their values were passed as strings, instead they should be defined like this:

```
"core_count": 4,
```

This should be the same for all the other variables with the type **number**.

2. Typo:

In your tfvars file, there is a typo in **snasphot_id** that needs to be changed to **snapshot_id**.

Since you did not provided the exact line where your errors occurred, I would assume that these are the main issues you have with your tfvars, and that your input should look more like this:

```
ec2_launch_template = [
  {
    "core_count": 3,
    "default_version": 1,
    "ebs_volume": [],
    "iam_instance_profile_arn": "arn:aws:iam::114833826347:instance-profile/testing-ec2-role-manoj",
    "image_id": "ami-05637405f4b0773e4",
    "instance_requirements": [],
    "instance_type": "t2.medium",
    "key_name": "RDSTEST",
    "lt_security_group_names": ["RDP"],
    "name": "testtemplate6",
    "tags": {"Name": "testtemplate6"},
    "threads_per_core": 2,
    "user_data": "testdata.sh"
  },
  {
    "core_count": 4,
    "default_version": 1,
    "ebs_volume": [
      {
        "device_name": "/dev/sdb",
        "ebs_block_delete_on_termination": false,
        "encrypted": true,
        "iops": 10000,
        "kms_key_arn": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:114833826347:key/7ed65523-f8ec-40f1-889e-ee65f7e58172",
        "snapshot_id": "snap-00a70b80c54bb6af5",
        "throughput": 125,
        "volume_size": 50,
        "volume_type": "gp3"
      }
    ],
    "iam_instance_profile_arn": "arn:aws:iam::114833826347:instance-profile/testing-ec2-role-manoj",
    "image_id": "ami-05637405f4b0773e4",
    "instance_requirements": [
      {
        "cpu_max": 3,
        "cpu_min": 2,
        "memory_max": 80,
        "memory_min": 20
      }
    ],
    "instance_type": null,
    "key_name": "RDSTEST",
    "lt_security_group_names": ["RDP"],
    "name": "testtemplate5",
    "tags": {"Name": "testtemplate5"},
    "threads_per_core": 2,
    "user_data": "testdata.sh"
  }
]
```

Comment: Tried this,  it's still giving error